# Slow execution in reading and writing of json file

Tags: php

The code I currently have as pasted below simply (or not so simply) reads an existing json file and appends a new record to the file after the '[' character, so skipping one line. The problem is this whole process of reading and writing produces very slow results. This is for a dice game, user roles the dice and the score is written to a json file, a jquery script reads the file in to a table.

```
function writeJson($player, $result, $bet, $betamount, $profit) {
   $id=uniqid();
   $response = array(
      'player'=> $player, 
      'result'=> $result,
      'bet'=>$bet,
      'size'=>$betamount,
      'profit'=>$profit,
      'id'=>$id
    );

   $lines = file('dice.json');
   $oldlines='';
   foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
     $oldlines.=$line."\r\n";
     if($line_num==0) { //insert new record here. 
        $oldlines.=json_encode($response).",\r\n"; 
     }
   }
   file_put_contents('dice.json',preg_replace('/^\h*\v+/m', '', $oldlines));
   clearstatcache();
}
```

here is the format of a json file generated by this code.

```
    [ 
    new records will be inserted at this location
{"player":"seang","result":"EVEN","bet":"ODD","size":"0.00000005","profit":"-0.00000005","id":"57b9ace6ce133"},
    {"player":"seang","result":"EVEN","bet":"ODD","size":"0.00000005","profit":"-0.00000005","id":"57b9ace1c73f4"},
    {"player":"seang","result":"ODD","bet":"ODD","size":"0.00000005","profit":"+0.00000005","id":"57b9acd8dd50a"}
    ]
```

Comment: Unclear. What is your question ? How slow is "very slow results" ? Please give us some more.

Comment: Well I guess basically the ultimate question is: is there a better more efficient way of doing what I am doing. The way I am currently doing it is..well.. slow, Overkill? Not sure how else to word it :)

Comment: Don't you try to use MySql for storing your information. It's would be really easier to handle your structure.

Comment: i figured that'd be slower even than using json? but it did cross my mind

Comment: I think, it would be much better, there're some nosql approaches, like redis or mongodb to store your data in json format right in your memory. It's the faster way to get data nowadays.